# Python 2.7 to Python 3 upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on updating a series of python 2.7 plugins to python 3.10 that get loaded into the software individually. Below is an example of how the python 2.7 plugin is organized.

ProjectDir

- Plugin1

  - `__init__.py`
- Plugin2

  - `__init__.py`
- Plugin3

  - `__init__.py`
- Common

  - CommonFunctions.py

All three of the plugins use functions out of the CommonFunctions.py file. When I have updated the import statements for the three plugins to

```
from ..Common.CommonFunctions import Example1
```

I get the exception:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Based off of my research this is due to the Common directory not being in the same directory as the **init** folder (or one of its subfolders). Is there a way to solve this issue without copying the Common directory to each plugin?

I have verified that when I do copy the folder over the issue is resolved. However, that is not a desired solution.

Comment: It would just be `from Common.CommonFunctions import ...`, assuming `ProjectDir` is on `sys.path` as itself. What is this software you're plugging into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would just be `from Common.CommonFunctions import ...`, assuming `ProjectDir` is on `sys.path` as itself and is not a package.

(If `ProjectDir` *was* a package, the original relative import would work anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've populated your `__init__.py` files correctly (each public function/class in your Python files are imported in the `__init__.py` files), you can simply use absolute imports.

This includes having a `__init__.py` in the root directory `ProjectDir` that imports `Plugin1`, `Plugin2`, `Plugin3` and `Common`.

This is what your project should look like. Each `__init__.py` should import functions that are at the same level (e.g., `Plugin1` imports functions from `plugin1.py`, same for the other directories):

```
ProjectDir
|-- __init__.py
|-- Common
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- CommonFunctions.py
|-- Plugin1
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- plugin1.py
|-- Plugin2
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- plugin2.py
|-- Plugin3
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- plugin3.py
```

Example:

```
from ProjectDir.Common.CommonFunctions import Example1
```